# Equivalent of Angular 1's decorator in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

In Angular 1 there was a concept of substituting or extending the built-in services with [decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators).

Is this an accepted idiom in Angular 2? If so, what is the best-practice way of doing so?

Edit: Not to be confused with the concept of decorators in TypeScript.

Comment: I think typescript's decorators give similar behavior

Answer (score 0):

May be **UseClass**, **UseFactory**, **UseValue** & **UseExisting** are what you are looking for

https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2018/08/17/using-useclass-usefactory-usevalue-useexisting-with-treeshakeable-providers-in-angular/

Comment: That would seem to work for the case of services. In angularjs, you could also decorate directives. This would allow us to do things like add default attributes to components or otherwise modify a component's template. Is there anything similar in angular 2?